# Pandas KeyError: <type 'object'> on dataframe.resample().mean()

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have to fix some legacy code which changes daily sample data like this:

```
sample_data = [
    {
        'id': 10,
        'name': 'example',
        'tags': '["one", "two"]',  # json encoded
        '2016-12-20': 2,
        '2016-12-21': 3,
        '2016-12-22': 10,
        '2016-12-23': 4,
        '2016-12-24': 7,
        '2016-12-25': 5,
        '2016-12-26': 1,
        '2016-12-27': 6,
        '2016-12-28': 4,
        '2016-12-29': 3,
        '2016-12-30': 1,
    },
    {
        'id': 11,
        'name': None,
        'tags': '["one"]',  # json encoded
        '2016-12-20': 6,
        '2016-12-21': 10,
        '2016-12-22': 190,
        '2016-12-23': 77,
        '2016-12-24': 35,
        '2016-12-25': 346,
        '2016-12-26': 6,
        '2016-12-27': 9,
        '2016-12-28': 8,
        '2016-12-29': 3,
        '2016-12-30': 0,
    }
]
```

into weekly means. The code itself looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=sample_data)
df.set_index(['id', 'name', 'tags'], inplace=True)
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
df = df.replace(0, 1000)
df = df.T.resample('W')
df = df.mean()
df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df = df.round()
df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
result = df.T.reset_index().to_dict(orient='records')
```

However, I get an error during execution. The code is dealing with large amounts of data (>10k rows), and the error only seems to happen occasionally. The traceback follows:

```
  File "[...]/api/helpers.py", line 277, in resample
    df = df.mean()
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 540, in f
    return self._downsample(_method)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/resample.py", line 693, in _downsample
    self.grouper, axis=self.axis).aggregate(how, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3704, in aggregate
    return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3193, in aggregate
    result, how = self._aggregate(arg, _level=_level, *args, **kwargs)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/base.py", line 432, in _aggregate
    return getattr(self, arg)(*args, **kwargs), None
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 1047, in median
    return self._python_agg_general(f)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 818, in _python_agg_general
    for name, obj in self._iterate_slices():
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3123, in _iterate_slices
    yield val, slicer(val)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 3115, in <lambda>
    slicer = lambda x: self.obj[x]
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2057, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 2101, in _getitem_multilevel
    loc = self.columns.get_loc(key)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/multi.py", line 1686, in get_loc
    mask = self.labels[i][loc] == self.levels[i].get_loc(k)
  File "[...]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/indexes/base.py", line 2136, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 132, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4145)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 154, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:4009)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 732, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13166)
  File "pandas/src/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 740, in pandas.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item (pandas/hashtable.c:13120)
KeyError: <type 'object'>
```

I cannot seem to fix it, no matter what I do, and I'm not very experienced in Pandas. Is there something wrong with the code that I haven't noticed? Thank you for your time.

Comment: What is your verson of pandas? for me it works with your sample data perfectly.

Comment: Same here, looks like a version matter. Pandas 0.19.2

Comment: numpy==1.11.3; pandas==0.19.2. I should add that the code in question is dealing with very large amounts of data, and the error only happens when provided with said very large amounts of input data.

Comment: You could try using a [Python debugger](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDebuggingTools) to find out what the value of `key` is that causes the KeyError.